# Can AsyncCallback use a non-static delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, ipc, iasyncresult

I'm using .net remoting, with asynchronous function calls to handle the ipc of my current project.

I'm running into an issue where I'd like the client to:

1. ASynchronously request information
2. Continue loading the GUI
3. When the ASynchronous call is complete, load it into the gui

I do this with the following code

```
  GetFileTextDelegate ^svd       = gcnew GetFileTextDelegate(obj, &BaseRemoteObject::GetFileText);
  AsyncCallback       ^callback  = gcnew AsyncCallback(RecievedSomething);
  IAsyncResult        ^arValSet  = svd->BeginInvoke(callback, nullptr);
```

In the above example, **RecievedSomething** MUST be a static method in this example.  Why is that?  If I could make this function non-static, I could load my gui, and alls well.

My solution is to have RecievedSomething fire off a static event that my gui subscribes to.  This is cumbersome in that it will now require 2 delegates and an event to have my 1 asynchronous function call handled.

Is there a way to hace AsyncCallback work with a non-static function?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for a well-written question. -1 for using a C# tag and then writing C++CLI code. <shudder> I get seasick looking at the shameful, ugly mess that is C++CLI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a non-static method for your `AsyncCallback` delegate.  You just have to specify it correctly.  For example, to use `this->ReceivedSomething`:

```
AsyncCallback ^callback  = gcnew AsyncCallback(this, &MyClassType::RecievedSomething);
```

Comment: I'll give this a try first thing monday morning, thanks! I didn't put two and two together and realize that AsyncCallback's is just a delegate, and its constructor should operate like one.